# Saving record in multiple entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Hi I have two entities with navigation properties like this:

```
entity1                   entity2
------                   -------
entity1_id               entity2_id
name                     location
loc                      entity1_id
-----                    -----------
Navigation properties    Navigation properties 
entity2                  entity1
```

I have a model class:

```
public class Main 
{
public string name {get: set:}
public string loc {get: set:}
public string location {get: set:}
public int entity1_id {get; set;}
}
```

In my web api I am trying to write this record that is the model

```
public HttpResponseMessage Postentity1(Main main)

       {
                db.entity1.Add(main);
                db.SaveChanges();
            };
```

It doesn't work. The values of main are not being saved. Please let me know how can I save the record. Thanks

Comment: What is db ? The DataContext ?

Comment: If its EF, db has to be the context and context.entity1 be the object that represents table 'etity1'

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint to make sure that `Postentity1` gets executed? If it gets executed do you get an exception?